# What is the difference between quo and quando as relative pronoun?

Tags: relative-pronouns

[Genesis 2:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202&version=VULGATE) reads as follows in the Latin Vulgate:

> Istae sunt generationes caeli et terrae, quando creata sunt, in die quo fecit Dominus Deus caelum et terram

*Quo* and *quando* were used both as a relative pronoun meaning 'when' as in the above sentence.
what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6):

The question “what is the difference between them” is somewhat vague. *Quo* and *quando* have little in common besides the fact that both start with *qu* and end in *o*. In particular, it is not true that “quo and quando were used both as a relative pronoun meaning 'when'” in this sentence.

- *Quando* is a conjunction meaning “when.”
- *Quo* is a relative pronoun and does not really mean “when” but “which” or “that.”

In this case *quo* is in the ablative, which we have to render in English somehow, seeing how we don't have an ablative in English. How exactly we render it depends on which type of ablative usage it is, in this case an ablative of time; therefore *dies, **quo** fecit Dominus Deus* means “the day **on which** the Lord God made …” and so on.

Actually, it happens that you can leave the “on” out in English, as in the KJV text of Gen. 2:4 —

> These are the generations of the heavens and of the earth **when** they were created, in the day **that** the Lord God made the earth and the heavens.

(emphasis mine, obviously). Note: Presumably this is not a translation from the Latin, of course – but it renders the same meaning anyway.